# Setting background image for navigation bar sometimes displays incorrectly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

[image]

If I am setting a navigation bar background image, it works fine in the application, but if I open this screen from my mail composer it will break. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code?

```
UIImage *gradientImage44 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]
                                    resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage44 
                                           forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomBackground)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
    [navBackgroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

@end
```